# Python - concatenate multiple files with logic

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to Python. I have multiple data set with the format below:

Sample data (there are atleast 30 txt files in this format)

```
[10]
#feel my cold hands.
#≥ª ¬˘ º’¿ª ¡ª ∏∏¡Æ∫¡.

[11]
#The model plane flew over the river.
#∏«¸ ∫Ò«‡±‚∞° ∞≠¿ª ≥Øæ∆∞¨¥Ÿ.

[15]
#Hello.
#안녕!.
```

I was able to remove the lines that starts with '[' and remove just '#' from starting character of the line for a single txt file. 
However, when I try to load all txt files, it is failing. Any suggestion? Thanks!

WORKING on single txt file:

```
with open("/path/path2/data.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        ''' Removing # in front of the sentence'''
        if line.startswith('#'):
            line = line[1:] #+ '\n'

        ''' Removing entire that begins with [ '''
        if not line.startswith('['):
            print(line, end = '')
```

NOT WORKING. Error: UnsupportedOperation: not readable

```
import glob2

filenames = glob2.glob('/path/path2/*.txt')  # list of all .txt files in the directory

with open('/path/path2/output.txt', 'w') as f:
    for file in filenames:
        with open(file) as infile:
            for line in f:
                ''' Removing # in front of the sentence'''
                if line.startswith('#'):
                    line = line[1:] #+ '\n'

                ''' Removing entire that begins with [ '''
                if not line.startswith('['):
                    print(line, end = '')
```

Comment: `with open(file) as infile:` then `for line in f:`. Should be `for line in infile:`

Comment: Thanks it worked for my sample data set!

Answer (score 0):

You have just made a small mistake with your variables, `f` is the `path` to the `file` and `infile` is the `file object`.

So, you are trying to iterate through the `path`, not the `file object` which is `infile`.

In addition, `glob` will give **all** `.txt` files - including `output.txt` that you are writing to. This throws the `error` that you are getting as you are trying to open a file for *reading* that you already have open for *writing*.

To get around this, we can just use a simple `if-statement`:

```
...
for file in filenames:
    if file == "output.txt":
        continue
    with open(file) as infile:
        for line in infile:
            ...
```